# Class.forName displayed in orange color in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Could anyone tell me why it's displayed in orange color even though the code is commented out? Please find the image below:

[image]

Comment: Press `Ctrl + F` - what are you searching for?

Comment: Oh, got it. Actually, I did search for it using `Ctrl + F`. Now I figured it out. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have typed Ctrl+F then somehow got that "Class.forName" in your search bar :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use block comment .. your current comment only hids the line above `Class.forName`..

Comment: I have `/*` starting before the `try{` block. So, everything is commented as shown.

Comment: Can we see the full class definition?(missed the /*)